# What does below syntax do request.config?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

what is param (request), how it is getting passed? and what does it do when request.config is called? what is config?

```
 def test_func(request): 
     request.config.getini('foo')
```

ANOTHER EXAMPLE

```
 @pytest.fixture
 def base_url(request):
      return request.config.getoption('--base-url')
```

Comment: While I can't say what the type of `request` is, you can `print(type(request))` or better yet, use a debugger to gleen more information about that thing. Conceptually, it looks like `test_func()` might load a configuration file "foo.ini" to set certain parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.config` in python used to access the configuration settings of the `request` object. In the context of testing with `pytest`, the request object represents the test request being executed.

```
def test_func(request):
    request.config.getini('foo')
```

- In this example `test_func` function takes a request object as a parameter. This function is likely a test function written using the pytest framework.
- Within the function, `request.config.getini('foo')` is called to retrieve the value of the 'foo' configuration option from the request object's configuration. This allows you to access specific configuration values for your tests.
  In second  Example

```
@pytest.fixture
def base_url(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--base-url')
```

- `@pytest.fixture` is a decorator used to define a fixture in pytest. `base_url` fixture is defined to retrieve the value of the `--base-url` option from the request object's configuration using `request.config.getoption('--base-url')`.
- The value of this option can then be returned by the fixture and used in tests that depend on it.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your explanation. I have a test automation background in Java, my new job requires automation using Pythom/Pytest, and was having trouble understanding who is sending the parameters in the below code snippet sequence, are they being passed by             PyTest                                                                         
   def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--ENV", action="store", default="test",
                     help="which environment to run your tests: dev or test")
    parser.addoption("--HOST", action="store", default="localhost",

Comment: The next function, how the parameter (config) is passed, is config pythons special property
def  pytest_configure(config):                                                                        
   config.env = config.getoption("--ENV")
    config.host  = config.getoption("--HOST").               
    config.platform =  config.getoption("--PLATFORM")

Next function (request) is passed are these params passed my PyTest Framework
def driver(request):
    env = request.config.env
    host = request.config.host
    platform = request. config.platform

Comment: Hope, I was able to explain the above function sequence. Just trying to understand who actually passed the parameters during the run time. The first function pytest_addoption(parser): passes a custom command line argument to Pytest

Comment: @GoatOmega i cannot explain all over on `comments`, your question is being closed by SO. you should try to read docs, you can ask again on SO, if you face any problem on being something specific, If you find above answer helpful you should mark accepted.